# CVaR minimization with the BDportfolio_optim function (PortfolioOptim package)

Tags: r

I'm trying to run an exemplary code using the BDportfolio_optim function from the PortfolioOptim package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PortfolioOptim/PortfolioOptim.pdf) in order to minimize the CVaR. The output should be the optimal weights for the minimum CVaR regarding some constraints.
However, I always run into an error saying that my first constraint matrix A has the wrong dimensions.
The used code  is very similar to the example used in the PortfolioOptim manual:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PortfolioOptim/PortfolioOptim.pdf

library(PortfolioOptim)
library(fPortfolio)
library(quantmod)
library(pacman)
library(timeDate)
library(timeSeries)

```
getSymbols("EBAY", src="yahoo", from= "2011-01-01")
getSymbols("MSFT", src="yahoo", from= "2011-01-01")
getSymbols("INTC", src="yahoo", from= "2011-01-01")
getSymbols("KO", src="yahoo", from= "2011-01-01")

portfolio_1 = cbind(EBAY$EBAY.Close, MSFT$MSFT.Close, INTC$INTC.Close, KO$KO.Close)
ret_p_1 = cbind(dailyReturn(EBAY), dailyReturn(MSFT), dailyReturn(INTC), dailyReturn(KO))
portfolioReturns_1 <- as.timeSeries(ret_p_1)
colnames(ret_p_1) <- tickers
portfolioReturns_1 <- as.timeSeries(ret_p_1)

k = ncol(portfolioReturns_1)
num = nrow(portfolioReturns_1)
port_ret = 0.05 # target portfolio return
alpha_optim = 0.95

a0 <- rep(1,k)
A <- rbind(a0,-a0)
b <- rbind(1+1e-8, -1+1e-8)
LB <- rep(0, k)
UB <- rep(0.5 ,k)

result <- BDportfolio_optim(portfolioReturns_1, port_ret, "CVAR", alpha_optim,
                          Aconstr = A , bconstr = b, LB, UB, maxiter=10000, tol=1e-8)
```

The output of the console is always the same:

```
Error in BDportfolio_optim(portfolioReturns_1, port_ret, "CVAR", alpha_optim,  : 
  Matrix A must have as many rows as constraints (=elements of vector b)  and as many columns as variables (=assets).
```

However, when I check the dimensions of A, it's (2, 4) - corresponding exactly to the elements of vector b and asset variables (k=4).

Does someone have an idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you missed part of the description of the [`BDportfolio_optim`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/PortfolioOptim/versions/1.1.1/topics/BDportfolio_optim) function's first parameter `dat` (your `portfolioReturns_1`), where it says:

> `dat` Time series of returns data; dat = cbind(rr, pk), where *rr* is an array (time series)
> of asset returns, for *n* returns and *k* assets it is an array with dim(*rr*) = (*n*, *k*),
> *pk* is a vector of length *n* containing probabilities of returns.

Your `portfolioReturns_1` consists only of the *rr* part and lacks the *pk* part.

> it seems that BDportfolio_optim only works using a return (probability) distribution as an input. Do you have an idea how I could assign one to portfolioReturns_1?

According to the example used in the PortfolioOptim manual, you could do this:

```
result <- BDportfolio_optim(cbind(portfolioReturns_1, matrix(1/num, num, 1)), port_ret, …
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this little detail! Meanwhile, I figured out that it is expecting an additional column, now I see which type it should be of.
Anyway, it seems that BDportfolio_optim only works using a return (probability) distribution as an input. Do you have an idea how I could assign one to portfolioReturns_1?
And in case you're familiar with portfolio optimization, do you know about a built-in CVaR optimization function that does not expect a return distribution as an input?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with portfolio optimization. Perhaps there's a better chance for an answer to that on another Stack Exchange site, e. g. [Quantitative Finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: But I'll add to the answer how you could add a _pk_ column to your data as it's done in the example used in the PortfolioOptim manual.